# Why this code freezes, when i'm trying to use write (man 2 write) function?

Tags: c, pipe, unistd.h

I'm trying to write test, in which some data should be read from file descriptor, so i'm using dup and pipe functions to check this.

```
 int main()
{
    char    *line;
    int     out;
    int     p[2];
    char    *str;
    int     len = 50;

    str = (char *)malloc(235436);
    for (int i = 0; i < 235436; ++i)
    {
        str[i]='h';
    }
    out = dup(1);
    pipe(p);
    dup2(p[1], 1);

    write(1, str, strlen(str)); //freezes there. malloc alocates memory, i've checked this with debuger
    close(p[1]);
    dup2(out, 1);
    get_next_line(p[0], &line);


}
```

And for some reason this code works perfectly although it does all the same.

```
str = (char *)malloc(1000 * 1000);
    *str = '\0';
    while (len--)
        strcat(str, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur in leo dignissim, gravida leo id, imperdiet urna. Aliquam magna nunc, maximus quis eleifend et, scelerisque non dolor. Suspendisse augue augue, tempus");
    out = dup(1);
    pipe(p);
    dup2(p[1], 1);

    if (str)
        write(1, str, strlen(str));
    close(p[1]);
    dup2(out, 1);
    get_next_line(p[0], &line);
```

Comment: You don't NUL-terminate `str` in the first.

Comment: it doesn't matter. I 've replaced strlen with actual size of string, and appended \0 to the end. It just stays on this line of code

Comment: Ok, then please edit your question with the actual code with this undefined behaviour fixed.

Comment: @Vladimir every one of the 235436 bytes is filled with `'h'` but no string terminator.

Comment: sorry guys, i'm an idiot. My ide responded after 30 seconds of waiting and this function is working. Actual problem really was with \0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using pipe on linux machine. 
Acording to this  [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) i'm trying to read more bytes, than pipe can contain. So, in this situation i need to create file an operate with it.

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("buffer", "rb+");
if(fptr == NULL) //if file does not exist, create it
{
    fptr = fopen("buffer", "wb");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you fix the `strlen` problem - i.e. `write(1, str, 235436)`)

You are writing to a pipe. This pipe is not being read. Therefore the `write` will block.

Get something to read from the pipe.

Comment: So, how should i fix this? i need to invoke read from pipe before write?

Comment: @Vladimir You can't read from the pipe "before write", because there's nothing to read at that time. Either you need to use non-blocking I/O (and accept that `write` may then return without writing everything) or accept that it may block until read _by some other thread/process_.

Comment: is using of another fd will improve my situation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in calling the strlen function!

```
strlen(str)
```

Because you didn't set the terminator at the end of the string.

Adding the following code after the initialization loop will fix the problem:

```
str[235435]='\0';
```

Comment: `sizeof str` is not a correct replacement, since `str` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: yes you are right, sizeof was removed!

Answer (score 0):

Typical `strlen` implementation:

```
size_t strlen(char *s)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while(*s++) len++;
    return len;
}
```

In other words, it determines the length of a string by incrementing a pointer to the start of the string until a null-terminator is reached. Since your buffer is just a block of the character `'h'` without a null-terminator, calling `strlen` on it has undefined behavior.

Your second code-example, where you explicitly add a null-terminator after calling `malloc` and then use `strcat` to write to the string repeatedly does not have this problem since string literals are automatically null-terminated.

Also, [don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) unless you need your code to be compatible with C++ as well.